# What this typescript method signature in the picture mean?

Tags: typescript, intellisense, ngrx

The following code is taken from the [ngrx example](https://github.com/ngrx/example-app/blob/master/src/app/containers/find-book-page.ts). The intellisense for the method `store.select` has a long signature with two arrows. What does this method signature mean?

The type definition file shows this signature:

`export interface SelectSignature<T> {
    <R>(...paths: string[]): Observable<R>;
    <R>(mapFn: (state: T) => R): Observable<R>;
}`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that it can either be:

1. A function that accepts some or more paths and returns an Observable of R values
2. A function that accepts a mapping function and returns an Observable of R values. The mapping function accepts T values and returns an appropriate R value.

Comment: What does a mapping function do?

Comment: In Rx, `select` projects an input value to an output based on the mapping function you supply. It is the Rx / asynchronous equivalent of `Array.map`.